# rows in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` class that contains a `UITableView`. When my `UIViewController` is loaded , i want only one row in my table initially (that says "create new task"). Tapping on this row the user will be able to create a new task. Once he creates a task and clicks the done button, the table will now contain two rows. One will show the task that he has created and the other will still show "create new task". User can remove the task that he has created too.
How to do this? I am not able to understand how to make my table have only one row in the beginning, and then change the number of rows after..

I am a newbie.. so if this seems to be a stupid question, feel free to feel irritated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `UITableView` only has one section, you just need to return:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1 + [[self tasks] count];
}
```

Then when you build out your `UITableViewCell` objects, if your `row` is 0, then you return the 'Create Task' row. Otherwise, if your row is `>= 1`, you build out a `UITableViewCell` for the task at index `row - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can send `reloadData` to the table view and it will ask its datasource for the number of rows. You have to return 1(for the "create new task" row) plus the number of tasks you have.

Comment: yess.. I am thinking of taking a NSMutableArray that initially contains one NSString object "create new task". then as the user will create new tasks, the size of the array will keep on increasing accordingly. and the number of elements in this array will correspond to the number of rows in the table.

Comment: Additionally, if he's only adding one row at a time, and he knows that new tasks will be added at the top or bottom of the list, he can (instead of calling `reloadData`) use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to add just the single row, in a way that's visually more appealing than triggering an entire refresh.

Comment: at ViewDidLoad, i will initialize the NSMutable array with "create new task". so the table will always contain one row.. no matter what..!!

Comment: Don't store "Create New Task" in the NSMutableArray. Only store actual tasks in that structure.